# combined 3D graphics with no interface

Tags: graphics3d

I'd like to combine several 3D graphics, but the interface, indicated by the arrow in the figure attached between them is alway present. How to eliminate it? Thanks in advance.

Here is my example:

```
  Graphics3D[{
      {EdgeForm[None], Opacity[0.1], Gray, 
       Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}, 0.5]}, 
      {EdgeForm[None], CapForm["Butt"], Opacity[0.1], Gray, 
       Tube[{{0, 2, 0}, {0, 3, 0}}, {0.5, 0.2}]},

      }, ViewPoint -> {0.8677796780444739`, 2.2396029175520074`, 
       2.383513625315694`}, 
     ViewVertical -> {-2.366747875495254`, -0.028635050478789906`, 
       1.8415006920431496`}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is that this is not possible using `Cylinder` or `Tube` primitives. BTW running your code produces a different image than the one you posted.

Comment: @YvesKlett, you mean the arrow that I added using mspaint?

Comment: Not the arrow, but the right part is also a regular cylinder, and not a truncated cone. Interestingly, this is done by `EdgeForm["Butt"]`. Without it, the object shows correctly as a cone (though with a rounded end).

Comment: @YvesKlett,@István Zachar, my figure is obtained in Ver. 8.0. It shows differently in ver.9, as is pointed out by  István Zachar.

Comment: @YvesKlett,@István Zachar, I think it is a bug for ver.9.0. You can see the same case in the documents by searching "Cone" in the help browser, and entering "Properties & relations".

Comment: Does `CapForm[None]` solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or perhaps you want this (two tubes):

```
Graphics3D[{
  EdgeForm[None],
  CapForm[None],
  Opacity[0.1],
  Gray,
  Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}, 0.5],
  Tube[{{0, 2, 0}, {0, 3, 0}}, {0.5, 0.2}]
  },
 ViewPoint -> {0.86, 2.2, 2.3},
 ViewVertical -> {-2.3, 0.0, 1.8},
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: quicker by tube]

Comment: Code or it didn´t happen :-P

Comment: OK, you caught me red-handed...

Comment: Why not a single tube? `Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 3, 0}}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.2}]`

Comment: @Simon Woods, yes, it is the simplest way.